Has the install location of /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/ changed under Ubuntu 24.04?
I have installed python3-colcon-common-extensions and separately confirmed that python3-colcon-argcomplete is installed.
sudo apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-colcon-common-extensions is already the newest version (0.3.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

sudo apt install python3-colcon-argcomplete 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-colcon-argcomplete is already the newest version (0.3.3+ds-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded

I cannot locate /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/colcon-argcomplete.bash even though the package/packages report as installed.
I generally source from /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/colcon-argcomplete.bash in .profile or .bashrc for colcon autocomplete.

The new path seems to be : /usr/share/colcon_cd/function/colcon_cd-argcomplete.bash

Thanks. I did see this but was troubled by the source of the changes. Seems like Colcon GitHub and Colcon Docs  dont mention this. Possibly a third source packaging bug?
